# Why does unpacking give results in tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am learning arbitrary value parameter and reading stackoverflow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-parameters) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs) answers and other tutorials I already understood what *args and **kwargs do in python  but I am facing some errors. I have two doubts, first one is:

If I run this code print(w) then I am getting this output:

```
def hi(*w):
    print(w)

kl = 1, 2, 3, 4
hi(kl)
```

output:

```
((1, 2, 3, 4),)
```

but if I run this code with `print(*w)` then I am getting this output:

code:

```
def hi(*w):
    print(*w)

kl = 1, 2, 3, 4
hi(kl)
```

output:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

My second doubt is:

```
je = {"a": 2, "b": 4, "c": 6, 4: 5}
for j in je:
    print(*je)
```

output

```
b a 4 c
b a 4 c
b a 4 c
b a 4 c
```

What exactly is `*je` doing there? How is it working in iteration?

Comment: You should read about packing unpacking of arguments http://hangar.runway7.net/python/packing-unpacking-arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use * in declaration of the arguments `def  hi(*w):`, it means that all the arguments will be compressed to the tuple, e.g.:

```
hi(kl, kl) # ((1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4))
```

After when you use print(*w) * run unpack of your tuple.

```
je={"a":2,"b":4,"c":6,4:5}
for j in je:
    print(*je)
```

In every iteration you use unpack of your dict (you use je and get the keys of your dict like [j for j in je])

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments

Comment: i thought in every iteration its multiplying the iteration value with len of dict values ??

Comment: you use 'for j in je:' so you iterate 4 times(it's a len of your dict). In your loop, on every iteration you make unpack of the keys (so you make 4 times the same operation)

Answer (score 2):

Your first case, it's because you're passing `kl` into the function as a tuple, not as arbitrary values. Hence, `*w` will expand into a single element tuple with `kl` as the first value.

You're essentially calling:

```
hi((1, 2, 3, 4))
```

However, what I suspect you want is

```
hi(1, 2, 3, 4)
# or in your case
hi(*kl)
```

When printing in python 3, `print` is a function, so again. When `w` is a tuple and you call it like:

```
print(w)
# you'll get the tuple printed:
# (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

However, again, you can call it with arguments like:

```
print(1, 2, 3, 4)
# or in your case
print(*w)
# 1 2 3 4
```

---

For your second part, look at it converted to a list first:

```
list({"a":2,"b":4,"c":6,4:5})
# ["b", "a", 4, "c"]
# Note, dictionaries are unordered and so the list could be in any order.
```

If you were to then pass that to print using the `*` expansion:

```
print("b", "a", 4, c)
# or in your case
print(*["b", "a", 4, "c"])
```

Just note, that the `*` does the default iteration for you. If you wanted some other values, use `je.values()` or `je.items()`